# add location.href to a script src

Tags: javascript, window.location

I'm not a javascript pro, and I need to achieve a simple thing. How can I add the current browser URL to a script src tag?

The end result should be:

```
<script src="http://example.com/script.js?ref= {location.href} "></script>
```

Comment: There is nothing that will do that from a pure html point of view. What server side technology are you using to service the pages? e.g ASP.Net, PHP, etc. Or are you trying to change the `src` attribute using javascript?

Comment: Sorry, I've noticed that the src was confusing. It's pointing to a .js page which is actually a PHP page. I want to use the ref parameter server-side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the createElement:

```
         var link = "http://example.com/script.js?ref="+location.href;
         script1 = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
         script1.type="text/javascript";
         script1.src = src1;
           document.head.appendChild(script1);
```

EDIT:

If you can append the script in the head or body putting

```
document.head.appendChild(script1);
```

or

```
document.body.appendChild(script1);
```

But if you can put in the specific point (id of one div or input), you can put with:

```
document.getElementById("NAMEOFID).appendChild(script1);
```

Comment: I'm placing the script somewhere in the body. How can I append the new script on the same position?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, sorry im not at computer so can't test

```
var scr = document.getElementByID('script_name');

<scr onclick="Goto">

function GoTo()
  {
    window.location = 'http://www.google.com'   
  } 
<script id="script_name> </script>
```